# Can't figure out this aborted(core dumped) in C

Tags: c

I'm building a function that searches for a word in a word search matrix from left to right, and I'm getting an aborted(core dumped).

The function:

```
void lefttoright(int rowcol, char **matrix, char* find){

    int i, j, k, q, len, count = 0;
    len = strlen(find)+1;

    for (i = 0; i < rowcol; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < rowcol; j++){
                    char* correct = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
                    if (matrix[i][j] == find[0]){

                            for (q = j; q < rowcol; q++){
                                    for (k = 0; k <= len; k++){
                                            if (matrix[i][q] == find[k]){
                                                    correct[k] = matrix[i][q];
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                            printf("%s\n", correct);
                            if (strcmp(correct, find) == 0){
                                    count++;
                                    free(correct);
                            }
                    }
                    else continue;
            }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

Through print statements I've found that

```
if (matrix[i][j] == find[0]){
```

seems to be the problem, but I could be wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is clearly that you `malloc()` *always*, even if there's no match. This will leak memory like crazy. Since you also don't `NULL`-check your allocation, it's possible you run out of memory and then fail due to writing to a `NULL` pointer.

You should run the program in a debugger to get a backtrace.